# a search container as input for sparql query

Tags: string, variables, search, sparql, sgvizler

I have a SPARQL query which I visualize using sgvizlers drucalagraph. I want to have a search container where a user can enter a musical artist. In the query as it is at the moment the user can not enter a musical artist. I want this part:

> ?song dbpedia-owl:writer dbpedia:Eric_Clapton.

to have a variable entered by the user instead of dbpedia:Eric_Clapton like it is at the moment. How do I do this?  Here is my code so far:

```xml
<div id="ex"
     data-sgvizler-endpoint="http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql" 
     data-sgvizler-query="

        SELECT ?song_label ?artist_label ?writer ?producer
WHERE {
       ?song dbpedia-owl:writer dbpedia:Eric_Clapton. ?song rdfs:label ?song_label . 
  OPTIONAL {{?song dbpedia-owl:artist ?artist} UNION {?song dbpedia-owl:musicalArtist ?artist.}}
  {?song dbpedia-owl:writer ?writer. }
  {?song dbpedia-owl:producer ?producer. } 
  {?artist rdfs:label ?artist_label .}

  #FILTER (?writer&&?artist!=dbpedia:Eric_Clapton)

  }  limit 100"
     data-sgvizler-chart="sgvizler.visualization.DraculaGraph"
    // data-sgvizler-chart-options="maxnodesize: 15; minnodesize: 2"
     style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid black; display: inline-block;">

</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do the query in SPARQL, or how to implement the search container in draculagraph? If it is the former question, then instead of '?song dbpedia-owl:writer dbpedia:Eric_Clapton.' I would add something like '?song dbpedia-owl:writer ?writer. ?writer dbprop:name "what the user entered here". (Or use the artist label). This way is a user enters "Eric Clapton" or "Clapton, Eric", you would retrieve that resource. Was that your problem?

Comment: thnx a lot for your help! I clicked the arrow on the left but accendentily clicked it again.. sorry.

Comment: I now have this code:

Comment: SELECT distinct ?clapton ?clapton_label ?artist ?artistlabel 
        where {?artist  ?pred  ?clapton

  {{?artist dbpedia-owl:associatedBand ?clapton} 
    UNION {?artist dbpedia-owl:associatedMusicalArtist ?clapton} }
 
   {?clapton rdfs:label '<?= ucwords($_GET['query']) ?>'@en. }
        ?clapton rdfs:label ?clapton_label .
          ?artist rdfs:label ?artistlabel .
      } limit 100

Comment: Did that solve your question? If it did then you should post it as an answer and mark it as resolved. In your query I think it is redundant to have the last couple of statements `?clapton rdfs:label ?clapton_label . ?artist rdfs:label ?artistlabel .` if you are previously binding the label to `'<?= ucwords($_GET['query']) ?>'@en. `

Comment: but it makes a draculagraph in which all are conntect to a single musical artist in the middel. (in this case I use the ?clapton variable as the source node) But I want also to show the connections between artists that are in the graph. So John Lennon would be the central node and he is connected to Paul McCartney and to Ringo Starr.  But I also want an connection between Paul McCartney and Ringo Starr. Is this even possible? and if yes, how?

Comment: it did solve my question. how do I post it as an answer?

Comment: Below there is a box with a "post your answer sign". If you have another question, then it might be worth it to start a new question instead of discussing it in the comments. But first, please check if it has been answered before! There are a lot of related sparql questions asking similar thing to what you have in mind.

Comment: like that? now it says the answer is mine and not yours

Comment: hehe, no. I suggest you to copy and paste the code you made to fix the problem, and explain why.

Comment: how can I do something which gives you the credit for the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63183/discussion-between-daniel-garijo-and-michamir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the rdfs:label of the resource as input for the query:

```
SELECT distinct ?clapton ?clapton_label ?artist ?artistlabel where {
{
  {?artist dbpedia-owl:associatedBand ?clapton} 
UNION 
  {?artist dbpedia-owl:associatedMusicalArtist ?clapton} 
} 
?clapton rdfs:label '<?= ucwords($_GET['query']) ?>'@en. 
?clapton rdfs:label ?clapton_label . 
?artist rdfs:label ?artistlabel . 
} limit 100
```